# Is there method to find element, satisfied particular conditions in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, search, reverse

I'm doing the program, that would find the prices of tickets with 'A-B' - like title and sum it with the 'B-A' ticket price.

So, I became curious, is there method, like `exists = x in` to find cells in dataframe, that would contain such `x`.

For example it could be 'AAQ' string, and I need to find 'AAQ-NUX' string, so I would like to present 'AAQ' and 'NUX' as `x` and `y` and find, in other dataframe, cell, that would contain 'NUX-AAQ', or, in my terminology, y+'-'+x string.

How can I realize it?

Below it is my tries to do that:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        if(j <= len(sum)):
            if(sum.loc[j]['flight'] == df2.loc[i]['flight']):
                if(exists = x in df1.CityCode_From & exists = y in df1.CityCode_To & exists = x+"-"+y in df2.flight & df2.loc[df2.flight == y+'-'+x]['flight'] == df.loc[i]['flight']):
                    sum.loc[j]['coupons'] = sum.loc[j]['coupons'] + df1.loc[df1.CityCode_From == x & df1.CityCode_To == y]['coupons']
            if(df2.loc[i]['flight'] == df1.loc[j]['CityCode_From']+"-"+df1.loc[j]['CityCode_To']): 
                sum = sum.append({'coupons' : df1.loc[j]['coupons'], 'flight' : df1.loc[j]['CityCode_From']+"-"+df1.loc[j]['CityCode_To']}, ignore_index = True);
                break
sum.head()
```